# Calling a function and returning a value from datatable

Tags: azure-application-insights, kql

I have some data in Application Insights logs. I am pulling back a number of items - one of which is an ID field. I would like to convert this ID field into a 'friendly name'.

For example:

ex1579 will mean nothing (but this is what is in my data). Instead ex1579 = Microsoft, and ex1580 = IBM. (I have hundreds of these).

I have created a function - that looks like this: (I am not sure if I am attacking this the best way)

```
let exMapping = datatable(id: string, company: string)[
"ex1579", 'Microsoft',
"ex1580", "IBM"
]
```

In my kql and I have many - I don't want to have to individually create CASE statements (which I know will work) - as this data will continually change.... and as opposed to updating multiple KQLs - I just want to maintain one datatable.

Going back to my KQL now - when I am returning ex1579 or ex1580 for example; instead of returning these values; I want to instead return (in this case) - Microsoft and IBM.

What is the best approach for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dictionary

Unlike Log Analytics, it seems that Application Insights doesn't currently supports function's parameters, so our function will return the entire dictionary and we will pick a specific key as part of our query.

This would be the function definition:

```
dynamic({"ex1579":'Microsoft', "ex1580":"IBM"})
```

This is how it can be used:

```
print id = "ex1579"
| extend company = getCompany()[id]
```

[image: Definition]

[image: Usage]

Comment: Thanks David, And I can define that once?

Right now - I have many KQLs and I don't want to have to maintain the first line that you have:

let exMapping = dynamic({"ex1579":'Microsoft', "ex1580":"IBM" });

I want to write it once (which is why I was thinking a 'function').

Then call that function in each of the KQLs.
By passing in the ID and it returns the company.

Comment: If I get your scenario correctly then you can define an Azure Monitor function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/functions

Comment: Exactly that David! I was proposing to create a single function:

let exMapping = datatable(id: string, company: string)[ "ex1579", 'Microsoft', "ex1580", "IBM" ]

Then I would call that function in each of my KQLs and instead of it returning ex1579 ... it would instead return Microsoft.

Now - when a new company comes onboard ... i would not have to update many KQLs...I simply update this one function.

So - really just need help in the function and calling the function to do the lookup to the friendly name.

Is that clearer? Thanks for your help btw.

Comment: See updated answer